# What should an iOS developer backup prior to a clean install of Lion?

Tags: iphone, ios, osx-lion, macos

Having already upgraded from Mac OS X 10.5 to 10.6, I really don't want to push my luck upgrading to 10.7. So when the time comes I am looking to do a clean install.  Please keep in mind that I am a relative newbie to Mac OS and so far every thing has, well, "just worked".  That being said ...

What should an iOS developer backup prior to doing a clean install of Lion?

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export any developer or distribution certificates from Keychain Access that you do not want to recreate.

Comment: Don't forget to export the private keys that go with each certificate.

Answer (score 1):

If you've been good about checking everything (including artwork, your own documentation, snippets, etc.) into an external source code control repository (and have tested this by building from a clean checkout into an empty directory), then all you really need to continue iOS development on any new or different Mac are your logins, certificates and private keys.  Just re-download the SDK appropriate for the Mac OS you are running.

But there might be a whole bunch of other stuff on your Mac in your User account that you might want to backup (iOS backups, music, photos, documents, etc., etc.)